# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown Menu active on Hover and Make Its dropdown Parent Clickable (linking)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow click on twitter bootstrap dropdown toggle link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630188/allow-click-on-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-toggle-link)

Well guys, I'm a little confused with the bootstrap navbar. I changed the dropdown menu active on :hover, like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ekjxu/, works fine. But what I wonder, how to make the first level menu of the dropdown menu?

1. First Menu (dropdown on :hover and clickable link)

   - 1st Submenu
   - 2nd Submenu
2. Third Menu
3. Fourth Menu

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you be more clear ? I don't get what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Cfontes as you can see, in my nav-bar menu: When I hover on (1. First Menu), it triggers the dropdown (that contains &bull; 1st Submenu and &bull; 2nd Submenu).

As a normal link (menu)... (1. First Menu) (href to http://somewhere.com/link) should be clickable and go through http://somewhere.com/link. What happen here, This (1. First Menu) only trigger the dropdown, no go to the link

I want to make (1. First Menu) clickable and go to http://somewhere.com/link

Comment: I answered this a few days ago - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12653488/609176). Note that it won't work on jsfiddle as they don't seem to let you redirect with anchors (although @Cfontes solution seems to work when setting target to parent)

Comment: @Ben I've flagged as duplicate

Answer (score 2):

If it's ok to open it in another window this should do it:

[On other tab](http://jsfiddle.net/ekjxu/438/)

otherwise this opens it in the same tab

[Same tab](http://jsfiddle.net/ekjxu/442/)

Comment: Thank for the help.
The fact is, I can't implement it when integrate it to real bootstrap. Nothing changes. Looks like I should dig more.