# twitter bootstrap dropdown links not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap version 2.0

I have the following html structure -

Now when I click on the `Filter by Team` the dropdown shows properly. Now when I click on the link, I should be taken to the page. But the links do *not* work. I mean, when I click on the dropdown elements, they should take me to a url, which they are href'ed to, this does not happen.

```
<li style="margin-left: 12px;">
        <div class="dropdown" style="margin-top: 5px;">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" style="margin-left: -2px;" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            Filter by Team
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">

            <li>
              <a tabindex="-1" class="disabled" href="/task/list/orgteam/8/">funvilla</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>

            <li>
              <a tabindex="-1" class="disabled" href="/task/list/orgteam/6/">Dev Team</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>

            <li>
              <a tabindex="-1" class="disabled" href="/task/list/orgteam/5/">Design Team</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>


          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
```

The fiddle can be found here - http://jsfiddle.net/ktgrw/

Comment: what version of bootstrap you use?

Comment: bootstrap version 2.0.4

Comment: what do you mean not working? like href="#" when clicked? do you have any code @ the class="disabled"?

Comment: What is class="disabled" on anchor tag doing?

Comment: disabled comes from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630188/allow-click-on-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-toggle-link

Comment: so you added the disable class to try to solve your problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that you have the `data-toggle` attribute set for the `<ul>`, that attribute is just for the link that you want to open/close the dropdown, remove it and the links should work.

Here's the **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/EHszH/)** with the correct bootstrap version and the attribute removed.

Also the `disabled` class is used on the toggle link to prevent the opening of the dropdown, you should remove it from your links since it's not serving any real purpose.

Comment: why the downvote? the extra attribute is what's causing the links not to work

Answer (score 0):

The links are working perfectly fine. When we use relative links like `href="/task/list/orgteam/5/"` we need to be sure that we are running this page on a website where these links exist.

To add to clarity, I added a link to google as the last list item in [this new fiddle (click here to view)](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaranjan/ktgrw/7/) and because it uses absolute url `href="http://www.google.com"`, it works just fine.

Comment: the fiddle link for google is not working. I am using chrome browser.

Comment: inside fiddle, i the links don't work. if you right click and say, 'open link in new window' the link works - suggesting if this code was to be used on a webpage, it would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem with bootstrap framework and at the end got the solution (worked for me).
Import all your required javascripts, mainly **jquery.js** .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the **data-toggle** attribute set for the `<ul>`, that attribute is just for the link that you want to open/close the dropdown, remove it and the links should work.

I had the same problem too but after removing the ***data-toggle*** attribute, my `<a>` links are working just fine.