# How to make dropdown header linkable?

Tags: hyperlink, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation, navbar, toplevel

Trying to make my site extrasmall device compatible with bootstrap 3 I became to use navbar component everywhere in navigation. It led to top levels links became unclickable. Now all links that having the child links leads to no where. Every time you click at them the group of its childs links appears or disappears and thus you can't visit pages that top level links were leading to. I hope I spoke with clarity.

[image]

How can I make my navigation be suited for extrasmall devices and top level links be visitable also?

Comment: You need to give more information. Show us your html code or create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Mivaweb, here is the site http://antilopagold.su.xsph.ru/ which should be examined at screen width less then 768 px. If you click at word "Категории +" navbar will become uncollapsed. Then you can click the first link called "Кожгалантерея" with a litle triangle at the right. What I'm talking about is exact this "Кожгалантерея" link which have an <a> tag inside but you will never visit the page that it points to. Everytime you click any of top level links having childs you see only openning or closing of their child links. But how to make it possible to come through that hidden link?

Comment: let me attach the screenshot that explaining the problem http://storage4.static.itmages.ru/i/15/0527/h_1432712384_2541083_9de8e53f3b.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3: how to make head of dropdown link clickable in navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935480/bootstrap-3-how-to-make-head-of-dropdown-link-clickable-in-navbar)

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution - http://jsfiddle.net/05hs57wa/4/
and here is the key part of a changed code:
`<li class=" dropdown">
    <a href="someurl" >Leather goods</a>
    <span class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"></span>...`

Last thing remains. Would you tell me how to make the second plus icon to be vertically aligned relative to the word "Leather goods" by means of some bootstrap styles or css styles? I need this icon to be to the right of the "Leather goods" row at the same time