# Yii2 : Create custom menu

Tags: yii2, yii2-widget

I had constructed a bootstrap menu and now I want to reproduce it with Yii2 Nav widget. So, here is the initial state:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">BrandLogo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#1" class="current">simple menu</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#4">dropdown menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#2">Submenu#1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#3">Submenu#2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback search">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And here is how it looks like:
[image]

Now I would like to do the same menu with Nav widget. Here is the code:

```
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'BrandLogo',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse',
    ],
]);

$menuItems = [
    [
        'label' => 'simple menu',
        'url' => ['#1']
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'dropdown menu',
        'url' => ['#4'],
        'items' => [
            [
                'label' => 'Submenu#1',
                'url' => ['#1'],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Submenu#2',
                'url' => ['#2'],
            ],
        ]
    ],
    [
        'label' => '
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback search">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
            </form>',
        'encode' => false,
        'url' => false,
    ],
];


if (count($menuItems)) {
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
        'items' => $menuItems,
    ]);
}

NavBar::end();
```

The problem is that the results aren't equal. I found a few problems:

1. The widget generates dropdown link as `<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="/main/#4" data-toggle="dropdown">dropdown menu <span class="caret"></span></a>` How can I get rid of `data-toggle="dropdown"` and `class="dropdown-toggle"`?
2. The search form is wrapped into `<a></a>` tags. That is why the navbar is broken:
   [image]
   How can I get rid of the unnecessary tag?

Comment: can you add the actual working `html` structure that you have to create/transform the navigation using Yii2 Nav

Comment: It is alreay there - the first code block named "initial state".

Comment: If somebody asks about why I want get rid of `data-toggle` and `dropdown-toggle` here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935480/bootstrap-3-how-to-make-head-of-dropdown-link-clickable-in-navbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are not following the actual HTML structure, and according to that you need to add the form after the `ul` not inside the `li`, but that form should be part of the `NavBar` and if you look into the defination

> Any content enclosed between the `\yii\bootstrap\begin()` and
>   `\yii\bootstrap\end()` calls of NavBar is treated as the content of the
>   navbar. You may use widgets such as `yii\bootstrap\Nav` or
>   `\yii\widgets\Menu` to build up such content.

so just move your form outside the `$items` after you are calling the `Nav::widget()` and before you call the `NavBar::end()`.

And you can use the `linkOptions` to customize or remove the class or any other attribute related to the link

```
<?php
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'BrandLogo',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse',
    ],
]);

$menuItems = [
    [
        'label' => 'simple menu',
        'url' => ['#1']
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'dropdown menu',
        'url' => ['#4'],
        'linkOptions' => [
            'class' => 'my-class',
            'data' => [
                'toggle' => ''
            ]
        ],
        'items' => [
            [
                'label' => 'Submenu#1',
                'url' => ['#1'],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Submenu#2',
                'url' => ['#2'],
            ],
        ]
    ],
];


if( count($menuItems) ){
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
        'items' => $menuItems,
    ]);
}
?>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback search">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></i>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
NavBar::end();
```

### EDIT

if you are looking to completly remove the class name `dropdown-toggle` then you might have to override the `yii\bootstrap\Nav::renderItems()` by extending the widget because it is added by default as the bootstrap class so you have to just copy the `renderItems()` to your extended class and comment out the line `Html::addCssClass ( $linkOptions , [ 'widget' => 'dropdown-toggle' ] );` which adds the class there and then change the `namespace` where you are calling the `Nav` from `yii\bootstrap\Nav::widget()` to `common\components\Nav::widget()`

Add the following class in your `common\components\` or if you plan to copy it somewhere else do update the namespace in the code

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace common\components;

use yii\bootstrap\Nav as BaseNav;
use yii\bootstrap\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;

class Nav extends BaseNav {

    /**
     * Renders a widget's item.
     * @param string|array $item the item to render.
     * @return string the rendering result.
     * @throws InvalidConfigException
     */
    public function renderItem($item) {
        if( is_string($item) ){
            return $item;
        }
        if( !isset($item['label']) ){
            throw new InvalidConfigException("The 'label' option is required.");
        }
        $encodeLabel = isset($item['encode']) ? $item['encode'] : $this->encodeLabels;
        $label = $encodeLabel ? Html::encode($item['label']) : $item['label'];
        $options = ArrayHelper::getValue($item, 'options', []);
        $items = ArrayHelper::getValue($item, 'items');
        $url = ArrayHelper::getValue($item, 'url', '#');
        $linkOptions = ArrayHelper::getValue($item, 'linkOptions', []);

        if( isset($item['active']) ){
            $active = ArrayHelper::remove($item, 'active', false);
        } else{
            $active = $this->isItemActive($item);
        }

        if( empty($items) ){
            $items = '';
        } else{
            $linkOptions['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
            Html::addCssClass($options, ['widget' => 'dropdown']);
//            Html::addCssClass ( $linkOptions , [ 'widget' => 'dropdown-toggle' ] );
            if( $this->dropDownCaret !== '' ){
                $label .= ' ' . $this->dropDownCaret;
            }
            if( is_array($items) ){
                $items = $this->isChildActive($items, $active);
                $items = $this->renderDropdown($items, $item);
            }
        }

        if( $active ){
            Html::addCssClass($options, 'active');
        }

        return Html::tag('li', Html::a($label, $url, $linkOptions) . $items, $options);
    }

}
```

Comment: My second question is completely solved! Thank you. Unfortunately I still get `dropdown-toggle` class in output html. `<a class="my-class dropdown-toggle" href="#4" data-toggle="">dropdown menu <span class="caret"></span></a>`. Now I can add my own class, but still can't remove existed one.

Comment: well if you are looking to completly remove the class from there you might need to override the `yii\bootstrap\Nav::renderItems()`  as the class is added by the widget, i have update the answer see he edit section @GHopper